# Trying to pass a type ("object") created in program 1 to a function in program 2

Tags: function, go

I have spent quite some time with python and am now trying to learn golang.  I'm trying to do something in golang that I do often with python; essentially create an object in one program but then pass that object to a method (or function) in another.

I know golang doesn't have objects, but I'm also of the opinion that I should not have to define a type that has already been defined.  My sample code follows:

program 1:

```
import (
    "github.com/bndr/gojenkins"
    "bitbucket.org/elsammons/senjink/actions"
)

func main () {

    jenkins := gojenkins.CreateJenkins(url)
    _, err := jenkins.Init()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    jobs = actions.GetAllJobs(jenkins)
}
```

Program 2:

```
package actions

import (
    "github.com/bndr/gojenkins"
)

//type Jenkins gojenkins.Jenkins
//type Jobs gojenkins.Job

func GetAllJobs(jenkins gojenkins.Jenkins) jobNames gojenkins.Job {
    return jenkins.GetAllJobNames()
}
```

I have tried other approaches as well, just as defining the type as commented out and using (jenkins *Jenkins) etc...  However I continue to get errors so I'm obviously missing something.

Appreciate any instruction here that might help me on my journey.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Your function `GetAllJobs` should receive a `*gojenkins.Jenkins` pointer instead, since that is what is returned by `gojenkins.CreateJenkins(url)` . You have not declared `jobs` yet (`jobs := actions.GetAllJobs(jenkins)`) . And `jenkins.GetAllJobNames()` doesn't return a `gojenkins.Job` value.

Comment: Go certainly has objects. An object is nothing more than a combination of state and behaviour, i.e. a value of a type with methods defined on it.

Comment: @cd1 the error I'm getting follows:  

 pwd
${HOME}/go/src/bitbucket.org/elsammons/senjink/actions
[esammons@bender actions]$ go build
# bitbucket.org/elsammons/senjink/actions
./search.go:10: syntax error: unexpected gojenkins after top level declaration

Comment: I have been able to make progress by removing the return values and changing AllJobs(jenkins gojenkins.Jenkins) to GetAllJobs(jenkins *gojenkins.Jenkins).  The last piece is the return piece, I  typoed the declaration of jobs, however, I worry that I still have that wrong because Job related items are defined in gojenkins, https://github.com/bndr/gojenkins/blob/master/job.go.

Comment: modified search.go, attempting to implement the return `func GetAllJobs(jenkins *gojenkins.Jenkins) *gojenkins.Job { return jenkins.GetAllJobs() } `  I'm still missing something because I get the following error ./search.go:11: cannot use jenkins.GetAllJobs (type func() ([]*gojenkins.Job, error)) as type *gojenkins.Job in return argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error you provided,

```
bitbucket.org/elsammons/senjink/actions ./search.go:10: syntax error: unexpected gojenkins after top level declaration
```

You should fix the syntax of your function's return type. If `jobNames` is the name of your return variable (which, by the way, isn't a recommended practice..), [you should surround both variable name and type with parentheses](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types):

```
func GetAllJobs(jenkins gojenkins.Jenkins) (jobNames gojenkins.Job) {
```

There seems to be other compile errors in your code (e.g. the return of `GetAllJobs` doesn't match the return of `gojenkins.Jenkins.GetAllJobNames`), but this should fix what you're asking for now.

Regarding your question, about passing an object from one program/library to another one, Golang does it just like every language: just pass the object with the exact type that the other side is expecting and you should be fine.

Comment: I have made some progress, not getting an error, too many arguments to return.  New search.go code, `func GetAllJobs(jenkins *gojenkins.Jenkins) (*gojenkins.Job) {
 return jenkins.GetAllJobs()
}`

Comment: The following may help, it is the gojenkins library i'm using,  github.com/bndr/gojenkins/blob/master/job.go

Comment: You need to match exactly the object types. The function gojenkins.Jenkins.GetAllJobs() return the type []*gojenkins.Job; your function returns what that function returns; so your function has to return that same type as well, instead of *gojenkins.Job.

Comment: So I got the above working, thank you @cd1.  I have since branched out a bit and am trying to actually do something that isn't already being done by gojenkins.  `jobs, _ := jenkins.GetAllJobNames() j := actions.SearchJobsByName(jobs)`  When I'm done I will return []gojenkins.job containing only those Jobs where name matches search.  The issue is in my search.go `func SearchJobsByName(jobs []gojenkins.job) []gojenkins.job` I get the error cannot refer to unexported name gojenkins.job; however, https://github.com/bndr/gojenkins/blob/master/job.go#L37 so I'm now officially confused.

Comment: There's a bad design decision there in returning an unexported type by an exported function...